# How to construct a flow diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

I would like to draw the flow diagrams attached in the photo as figures:

[image]

How can draw these in LaTex as figures?

Comment: Seems you already know where to search, as you specified `tikz` in the tags :)

Comment: @Bibi yes, but I don't know how to draw them :(

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that by yourself, spend some time to learn.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14159pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \sf
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, on grid]
        \tikzset{
            mynode/.style={circle, draw,minimum width=8mm,inner sep=0pt},
            myarrow/.style={-{Stealth[scale=1.5]}}
            }
        \node (1) {SI};
        \node [mynode,right=of 1] (A1) {S};
        \node [mynode,right=of A1] (B1) {I};
        \draw [myarrow] (A1) -- (B1) node[midway,above] {$\beta$};
        
        \node [below of=1] (2) {SIS};
        \node [mynode,right=of 2] (A2) {S};
        \node [mynode,right=of A2] (B2) {I};
        \draw [myarrow] (A2) -- (B2) node[midway,above] {$\beta$};
        \draw [myarrow] (B2) to[bend right=50] node[midway,above] {$\gamma$} (A2) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To be continued...

[image: evolutive graph]

Comment: Nice solution. However, you should note that the use of `\sf` is deprecated in LaTeX (as stated in [this document](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf)). Instead, you should use `\sffamily`. An even better way to change the font is to append `every node/.append style = {font = \sffamily}` to your `tikzpicture` environment global options instead of modifying it with a call to `\sffamily` before the beginning of the TikZ picture.

Comment: Thanks, it's a bad habit when I'm too lazy.

Comment: @SebGlav I want the drawing as a central figure, how can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `\begin{center}`?