# How to draw a flow diagram of this sort

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, flow-charts

I want to draw this diagram:

[image]

I have the following MWE (its not complete):

```
\sf
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, on grid]
        \tikzset{
            mynode/.style={circle, draw,minimum width=8mm,inner sep=0pt},
            myarrow/.style={-{Stealth[scale=1.5]}}
            }
        \node (1) {};
        \node [mynode,right=of 1] (A1) {S};
        \node [mynode,right=of A1] (B1) {I};
        \draw [myarrow, right=of 1] (1)--(A1)  node[midway,above] {$\mu$};
        
        \draw [myarrow] (A1) -- (B1) node[midway,above] {$\beta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hello. First, this is not a MWE, you may consider to put the complete minimal code here to get an answer. Secondly, in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583775/how-to-construct-a-flow-diagram/583780#583780, you got an answer  that doesn't need much effort to be adapted to what you're looking for here. Come back with questions about how to achieve something you struggle with, we will be happy to help ;)

Comment: @SebGlav I tried but I couldn't figure out how to draw the "bellow" arrows.

Comment: You can either define nodes with `node[below = of ...]` and draw an arrow afterwards, or draw your arrow and a node at the end with `\draw[myarrow] (S) --++ (0,-1) node[at end] {$\nu_S$};`.

Comment: @SebGlav the $\nu$ is very close to the arrowhead, how put it in the middle?

Comment: @SebGlav no worries, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need nodes or coordinates if you want to let an arrow start from or end nowhere. E.g.,

```
\draw[<-] (A) -- ++(-1,0);
```

will draw an arrow starting to the left of `(A)` and pointing to `(A)`. Similarly,

```
\draw[->] (A) -- ++(0,-1);
```

draws an arrow starting from `(A)` and pointing downwards.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, on grid]
  \tikzset{
    mynode/.style = {circle,draw,minimum width=8mm,inner sep=0pt},
    > = {Stealth[scale=1.5]}
  }
  \node [mynode] (A1) {S};
  \node [mynode,right=of A1] (B1) {I};
  \node [mynode,right=of B1] (C1) {R};
  \draw [<-] (A1) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {$\mu$};
  \draw [->] (A1) -- node[above] {$\beta$} (B1);
  \draw [->] (B1) -- node[above] {$\gamma$} (C1);
  \draw [->] (A1) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu$S};
  \draw [->] (B1) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu$I};
  \draw [->] (C1) -- ++(0,-1) node[below] {$\nu$R};
  \draw [->] (C1) to[out=135,in=45] node[above] {$\epsilon$} (A1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, you never fail to impress!

Comment: This is a side topic, but in a year or two, I'll be writing my Ph.D. thesis and I would like a LaTex "expert" to check and make corrections for a better all round document. Of course, I understand you're busy but if possible, do let me know if you'd be interested! I ask you since you've helped me a lot!

Comment: @Math I think you're better off going on learning by asking questions to experts like gernot on specific pointa. It's nice you have some time. You can think about your workflow to collect information, the type of objects (graphs, tables, page formats, etc) you'll need to show, etc You'll find most topics you'll need for your PhD on this site.

Comment: @Math Glad that I could help. Maybe there are people around on this platform that do professional typesetting and are willing to improve your document. I think there were some posts in this direction. Regarding myself, I'm heavily engaged in my job and do TeX.SX for fun (and I'm no professional in typesetting). I'd suggest that you concentrate primarily on the contents of the thesis, and otherwise follow JeT's advice. But if you are a perfectionist and have spare money, I'm sure there are people willing to help.

Comment: @gernot Yes, you're right in that I'm a perfectionist aha! I don't mind at all in spending money for a huge milestone in my life. When the time gets closer to actually writing up the thesis with the correct typesetting, I'll ask again. Also, I thank you for your help by answering my silly questions :)